# css trying to overlay divs

Tags: html, css

I have tried to layout the following view but I can't find a way to achieve this, I need to overlay 2 divs in this way:

[image]

To do this I have the following HTML and I tried to use this CSS:

```css
.general {
  @apply --layout-flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: 32px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  @apply --layout-horizontal;
  @apply --layout-center-justified;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container general">
  <div class="toolbar">

  </div>
  <div class="map">

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to make `div.toolbar` to have the width of the `.container .general` Div. I tried using flex to but I'm stuck with this, I will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.general`

```css
.general {
  @apply --layout-flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: 32px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  @apply --layout-horizontal;
  @apply --layout-center-justified;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.map {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container general">
  <div class="toolbar">

  </div>
  <div class="map">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate this, it works perfect and it is what i needed

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help. Please mark it as solution with the v-mark next to it, if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how important the structure of file is to you but simply nesting .toolbar in .map would achive that effect:

```css
.general{
    @apply --layout-flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }

  .toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    height: 32px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    @apply --layout-horizontal;
    @apply --layout-center-justified;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }

  .map {
    position: relative;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container general">

     <div class="map">
     <div class="toolbar">

     </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THanks for this other option, I really appreciate your time to help on this.